# Printing iframe in IE11 not working properly

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I currently have a print button that when pressed will create an iframe, fill it with html information, and print it to the user. This has been working (and is still working) perfectly in all browsers except IE11. For some reason in IE11 it is printing either the whole document or the parent element.

Here is all the necessary code.

```
var iframeEle = $("<iframe>").attr("id", "printIframe" + container_ele).css({ width: "0px", height: "0px" }).appendTo("body");
var doc = iframeEle[0].contentWindow.document;

//Open the document interface, write all stylesheets/html content to it, and close it
doc.open();
    //Get stylesheets
    $("link[type='text/css']", "head").each( function() {
        doc.write("<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='" + $(this).attr("href") + "' />");
    });
doc.close();

if(b_MSIE) { doc.execCommand('print', false, null); } 
else { iframeEle[0].contentWindow.print(); }
```

I am adding more content between closing the document and printing it, but that does not matter in this case.

Comment: Down vote really? With no question or explanation? I asked a straight forward question and provided all the details. If you dont like the code, or you cant solve the problem then thats not a reason to down vote.

Comment: Hello @Metropolis! take a look http://jsfiddle.net/yeEk7/3/ (I needed to alter your code to run on jsfiddle...) this works for me on IE. I think that need to close iframe tag...

Comment: @danilodeveloper did you test in IE11? The code I have closes the iframe properly. jQuery takes care of that. It is essentially the equivilent of $(document.createElement("div")). Unless that is broken in IE11 with jQuery.

Comment: @danilodeveloper Yeah I tried changing to what you have and its the same result. You may want to try and add more elements and content to that example inside and outside the iframe to see it better. I also would wonder how printing works in js fiddle if IE tried to print the whole page.